# mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting synology NAS drive

Tags: nfs, nas

My synology NAS will not let my ubuntu computer mount the shared NFS folder to a local folder for my plex server to read

[This is the error I get]
[Command]

```
sudo mount 192.168.0.27:/Volume1/Movies /Movies
```

[Error]

> mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.0.27:/Volume1/Movies

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue where my fstab from Ubuntu 16 worked, and under 18.04 does not. I found through experimentation that if I changed the permissions on the share from using *.fully_qualified_domain.us to 172.16.10.0/24 then I would be able to mount my volumes.

I opened an issue with Synology. Synology believes that dnsmasq daemon is ignoring the fully qualified name in the mount process.

From my fstab where "hostname.fullyqualified.us" is my fully qualified hostname.

```
hostname.fullyqualified.us:/volume1/music /media/coolwave/Music nfs ro,user,async,nolock,nfsvers=3 0 3
hostname.fullyqualified.us:/volume1/photo /media/coolwave/Photo nfs ro,user,async,nolock,nfsvers=3 0 3
hostname.fullyqualified.us:/volume1/homes/jcfowler /mnt/home nfs rw,user,async,nolock,nfsvers=3 0 2
hostname.fullyqualified.us:/volume1/Family /mnt/Family nfs rw,user,async,nolock,nfsvers=3 0 3
hostname.fullyqualified.us:/volume1/homes/pi /mnt/pi nfs rw,user,async,nolock,nfsvers=3 0 2
```

Comment: I just captured a Network trace showing the mount request from ubuntu 18.04.  The mount request is passing the hostname only and not the fully qualified name.  Is this an issue with dnsmasq or mount as NFS should use always use the fully qualified name?